# Extract the Data from the table with 10 min time range

Tags: sql

I need an SQL statement to select the data from the table with 10 min time range. Below is my table.

| Product | PurchasedTime | ProductNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 9:22:58 | 123 |
| ABC | 9:31:40 | 123 |
| ABC | 9:39:40 | 123 |
| DEF | 9:59:41 | 258 |
| DEF | 10:02:38 | 258 |
| GHI | 13:20:10 | 963 |
| GHI | 13:50:25 | 745 |

I need output like the below table.

| Product | PurchasedTime | ProductNo | TimeRange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 9:22:58 | 123 | 9:20 - 9:30 |
| ABC | 9:31:40 | 123 | 9:30 - 9:40 |
| ABC | 9:39:40 | 123 | 9:30 - 9:40 |
| DEF | 9:59:41 | 258 | 9:50 - 10:00 |
| DEF | 10:02:38 | 258 | 10:00 - 10:10 |
| GHI | 13:20:10 | 963 | 13:20 - 13:30 |
| GHI | 13:56:25 | 745 | 13:50 - 14:00 |

Comment: tag your DBMS and tell us what you have tried, SO is not a free coding site. but here is a hint : create a pseudo table contains the time interval and join it back into your current table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes your query to calculate time rage for each rows (in SQL Server):

```
select * ,(concat(datepart(hour,purchasedtime),':',(datepart(MINUTE, purchasedtime)/ 10)*10 ,' - ',datepart(hour,purchasedtime),':', ((datepart(MINUTE, PurchasedTime) / 10)+1)*10))TimeRange
from myproduct
```

**Output:**

[image]